# App Engine different response on browser vs postman

Tags: google-app-engine, postman

I have a nodejs express server running on app engine. 
If i make a GET request to https://astral-pursuit-252600.appspot.com/users in the browser it works fine to say unauthorized (401).
If I do the same GET request in postman it returns 400 bad request. 
Is there any obvious reason why this is occurring?

Comment: You might be sending extra or unnecessary headers that could be causing that error. I checked, for me, it is saying 401 only in postman also.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with postman. This tool sends certain headers by default that you cannot remove. App Engine does not like them for some reason. I had to use the Insomnia tool instead which does not include default headers.

Comment: some reference: https://community.postman.com/t/temporary-headers/5243

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I can think about is that, in order to do an API call, you need to use an [API key](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys) in your request. You should create one, after that you need to obtain an access token. Your requests should be send to an address like https://astral-pursuit-252600.appspot.com/users?key=YOUR_API_KEY and include in your request a header to contain the access token. Something like this : --header 'authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'.

In order to do that I do not think you need to change manually each request, but you need to change some POSTMAN settings. You can find [here](https://medium.com/@pnatraj/google-cloud-api-with-postman-f4cf070e665f) a guide with exactly what setting should be changed for this use case.

You can see more details about this topic and a more detailed guide for doing an API calls [here](https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/first-app).

In case this was not the issue, could you please provide me your POSTMAN settings? I am pretty sure this is about the way POSTMAN does the requests anyway.